# framework in xcode deleted by mistake

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods

This is my podfile for my iphone app.
    platform :ios, ‘9.0’
    use_frameworks!

```
target ‘NearBy Places’ do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 2.0.0'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
```

I accidentally deleted some files of framework. Now even when i run pod install command, it is still not able to get those files back and is showing me missing googlemapscore framework missing linker error.

Comment: did you try pod update command?

Comment: Delete the pod, run pod update and then add your pod and call pod update again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the pod, run pod update and then add your pod and call pod update again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after deleting `GoogleMapsCore` by mistake. Here's what worked for me:

1. From my project podfile, commented out the pods related to google maps, in my case

`rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'`

`pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path`

`pod 'GoogleMaps'`

`pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'`

2. ran cd ios then pod install , which removed the pods i commented out
3. then uncommented the pods i have commented earlier in step 1
4. repeat step 3 to install the pods again
5. ran a clean build on xcode and it worked.